# Can i make a function that returns an integer based on the key pressed (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using nodejs and i just need a function that when i call returns the value of the key pressed (0 if no key pressed).

I have tried using ioHook but that just executes a function whenever a key is pressed.

Comment: So you want to create a function, in which once you call it it tells you the last key pressed, correct? That really defeats the purpose of event listeners and I don't understand how you'll implement that. Please verify that I understood your question correctly?

Comment: It returns the key currently pressed, like in SDL getkeyboardstate, i don't need to wait for a key to be pressed, rather i just need to get the current key, to detect it in an infinite while loop @code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it on simple js
This is **not** on node js but the code should look like the same only with a different event listener name so I decided to post this and it may help you simulate it on backend

```js
const getCurrentKey = () => new Promise((resolve , reject) =>{

  function handleKeyDown(event){
      resolve(event);
      document.removeEventListener('keydown' , handleKeyDown) // removing the event listener so it'll not be triggered along with others next time
  }

  document.addEventListener('keydown' , handleKeyDown)

})
```

and it returns a **Promise** so for a simple example it can be used like below:

```js
async function test(){
  const e = await getCurrentKey();
}
```